# why indexedDB trigger onsuccess long time after open db in chrome

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

When open the page first, it takes a long time to trigger onsuccess events after indexedDB.open.(sometimes it takes 2000ms, but sometimes it's fast.)

This is a problem in chrome and IE, but not in firefox.
Firefox is stable to open within 100 ms.

```
_openDb: function () {
  var beforeTime = new Date().getTime(),
      request = indexedDB.open(self.dbName, self.version);

  request.onupgradeneeded = function (event) { /* ... */ };

  request.onsuccess = function (res) { 
    var curTime = new Date().getTime();
    console.log('open db: ', curTime - beforeTime);
  };

  request.onerror = function (e) { /* ... */ }

}

_openDb()
```

open page first:
chrome 69/72/75: open db:  4439
firefox: open db:  81

press F5:
chrome: db:  48
firefox: open db:  93

why chrome open action so slow, It only happened at first entry page. I suspect it's the Chrome browser problem，apologize for my incomplete description, and thanks for all help!